# SharePoint 2013 Autohosted App Feature Activation Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

We have created SharePoint 2013 Auto hosted app. In that, we have created near about 50 lists from the solution in visual studio. but when i deploy it, it gives following error:

"there was a problem with activating the app web definition."

What is the reason? any limit for creating lists in Auto hosted app?

Please suggest me...

Comment: have you followed the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920127.aspx

Comment: @rockinfresh Link and the actual problem are different. Is there any other solution can you provide? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint App Deployment error : 'Failed to install app for SharePoint'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349662/sharepoint-app-deployment-error-failed-to-install-app-for-sharepoint)